# Migrate existing IntelliJ Java EE 8 to Jakarta 9.1

Tags: intellij-idea, jakarta-ee, wildfly

I want to Migrate my existing Java EE 8 application to Jakarta 9.1.

I used IntelliJ IDEA 2022.2.1 (Ultimate Edition) to migrate:

```
Refactor | Migrate Packages and Classes | Java EE to Jakarta EE | Whole project | Run
```

When I recompile:

```
Build | Rebuild Project
```

When I get follow errors with each EJBs:

```
cannot find symbol symbol: class Stateless
cannot find symbol symbol: class LocalBean
cannot find symbol symbol: class TransactionManagement
cannot find symbol symbol: variable TransactionManagementType
```

I'm using:

```
Gradle 7.5.1
WildFly 26.1.2.Final - Jakarta EE 8 Full & Web Distribution
WildFly Preview EE 9.1 Distribution
openjdk version "18.0.2.1" 2022-08-18 OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 18.0.2.1+1-1)
IntelliJ IDEA 2022.2 & macOS Monterey 12.5.1
```

Can't seem to add the Jarkata 8 or 9.1 Classes/JARs to IntelliJ ?

Comment: Have you tried to reopen project after migration?

Comment: Of course Many times. Deleted ".gradle" etc.  rm -rf $HOME/.gradle/.

Answer (score 0):

Added new 'bean.xml':

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee/beans_3_0.xsd"
       version="3.0"
       bean-discovery-mode="all">
</beans>
```

Run:

rm -rf $HOME/.gradle/

Re-run x times:

```
Refactor | Migrate Packages and Classes | Java EE to Jakarta EE | Whole project | Run
```

Applied all post etc. and EAR'd again.

Answer (score 0):

I think it will only be necessary to create a new Jakarta company project then, In the window that will follow, you select the libraries required by your application according to the APIs available. so you select Jakarta EE 9 from the drop-down menu. Under Implementations, you select EclipseLink. Then you click Next. After the creation of the project, you will have to try to Add dependencies in your Gradle project. I think